# How can I use \nameref with custom \addsubsec command?

Tags: titlesec, nameref

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nameref}

% \addsubsec
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addsubsec{\secdef\@addsubsec\@saddsubsec}
\newcommand*{\@addsubsec}{}
\def\@addsubsec[#1]#2{\subsection*{#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
    \if@twoside\ifx\@mkboth\markboth\markright{#1}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\@saddsubsec}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\@mkboth{}{}}
\makeatother
% / \addsubsec

\begin{document}
    This refs to Ipsum\footnotemark{\footnotetext{\nameref{addsubsec:ipsum}}.
    \addsec{Lorem}
    \addsubsec{Ipsum} \label{addsubsec:ipsum}
\end{document}
```

I added a custom command to have `addsubsec` (unnumbered subsection).
This works pretty well.

For reasons I need `\usepackage{titlesec}`, but then the title in the footnote disapears. How can I use `titlesec` package with `nameref` in `addsec`?

Comment: What does your `\newcommand*{\addsubsec}{}` do?

Comment: I got that from here: http://www.matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=122935

Comment: Why do you need `titlesec`? Usage of `titlesec` with `scrartcl` is not recommended. Don't you want numbers for all sections and subsection or only some? Maybe changing `secnumdepth` would be better.

Comment: @TeXnician Even if you add `\usepackage{titlesec}`? IMHO MMM has not shown the example that shows the problem, but a example that does not show the problem unless you add `titlesec`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke No, I have not used one of the evil title* packages. I haven't seen that remark.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by replacing `\usepackage{titlesec}` with `\RequirePackage[loadonly]{titlesec}`.

Comment: Once again: Why do you load `titlesec`? `scrartcl` already provides an interface to modify or define section commands.

Comment: I am using this for `\titlespacing` which runs into error without package `titlesec`.

Comment: Usually you don't need `\titlespacing` with `scrartcl`. Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the spacing of a heading. And AFAIK if you load `titlesec` with option `loadonly` `\titlespacing` wouldn't change anything unless you also define the corresponding section command completely new. So I would again recommend to remove `titlesec` and replace the `titlesec` commands by `scrartcl ` commands.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thx for your hints! I appreciate them. :)